# Using C ampersand with or without brackets

Tags: c++, c, operator-precedence, ampersand, addressof

Let's have two lines of code:

```
&car->speed
&(car->speed)
```

1. Are these two lines equivalent? Will I get in both cases address to the `speed`?
2. If they are equivalents, what is better to choose as coding convention?

Comment: C(/C++) Operator precedences for your reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Are these two lines equivalent? Will I get in both cases address to the speed?

Yes. `->` has higher precedence than that of unary `&`, therefore `&car->speed` and `&(car->speed)` are equivalent.

> If they are equivalents, what is better to choose as coding convention?

Go with second as it shows the intended behaviour that you are interested in the address of `speed`.

Comment: I myself would go with the first: It is common enough that a middling C (or C++) programmer should know `[]` as well as `->` bind stronger that `&` in his sleep.

Comment: @Deduplicator; Its up to programmers precedence :P

Comment: Agreed.  The first is what every semi-capable C programmer would expect to see

Comment: I strongly agree with @Deduplicator. Excess parentheses are annoying. They cost reading time (I expect extra parentheses to be intended to *overrule* the normal precedence)

Comment: I agree with @haccks.  When there is a slight chance of ambiguity, then use parenthesis to be explicit.  The time it takes to type or compile two characters is insignificant to time wasted by a defect due to ambiguity.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Ambiguity would only exist if the code were being read by an beginner.  Next they would figure out the precedence and viola; now they know.  I don't write cryptic code if I can avoid it, but I also don't cater to programmers who don't know the language.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: While it is laudable that you want to avoid ambiguity, where none exists, prefer brevity: Things easier to understand because there's more of it to read. Also, don't write for someone in the first three weeks of learning programming, but for someone having mastered the basics, which this includes.

Answer (score -2):

This question already asked here several times. Postfix expression operators have higher priority than unary operators. So these two expressions

```
&car->speed
&(car->speed)
```

are equivalent.

Or another similar example with other unary operator !

```
!car->speed
!(car->speed)
```

As for coding convention I would prefer

```
&car->speed
```

and if you want to ampersandify `car` alone, use this:

```
( &car )->speed
```

Comment: Ah ok, I get what you want to express. It might be worth to mention explicitly that `&car->speed` and `(&car)->speed` are **not** the same ... :-S